# Can I use declared objects in a different class without declaring the object again?

Tags: java

I've only recently started learning java and I ran into a problem. I have a few objects I made through the class constructor, and I want to use these declared objects in a different class. The contents of the objects are set through variables.

So a simple solution would be to set the variables to static and then calling them in the other class by doing (just as an example)

```
 Originalclass.staticVariable
```

and using this as my parameter.

So lets say my original class is Firstclass, the object I want to make is called superObject, and my variable I want to apply in my object is called variableIneed. If I were to create my object in the other class, I would type

```
 Firstclass superObject = new Firstclass(Firstclass.variableIneed);
```

This worked, but I want to know, would it be possible to create the object in the original class and then use it in a different class? Is there a benefit to doing that?

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate question or it's not specific enough, this is my first post. :)

If my code will help answer my question, I will be happy to put it up, but I feel like it is kind of irrelevant to what is being asked since my code is fine.

Comment: It couldn't hurt to see the code.

Comment: ever heard of getters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create an object in a class, you usually do not want to "share the objects created" by simply making it as `static` (especially when you are not sure what static means).

Do not abuse `static`. `static` members actually belong to the class itself and not a particular object. So before you start declaring variables as `static`, you want to consider is it a property which belongs to the class? Or it is a property which belongs to individual object?

Further more `static` variables are shared among all objects. (You only have one copy of it). Hence if you share it across many other classes, there is a likelihood that its value may get changed from anyone of the classes you "shared" it to, making your classes tightly coupled (and you want to prevent this).

Unless the object belongs to the class and maybe it is a constant (declared as `final`), you may not want to share it by declaring it as `static`.

> This worked, but I want to know, would it be possible to create the object in the original class and then use it in a different class? Is there a benefit to doing that?

If I were you, and if I need to "share" my objects with other classes, I will pass it through a method (a getter method).

**Exmaple:**

```
class Car{
    private Engine engine;

    //Constructor not shown

    //a getter method
    public getEngine(){
        return engine;
    }
}

class Runner{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Car c = new Car();
        Engine engine = car.getEngine();  //retrieve engine from car (for whatever use)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating Firstclass with a static variable from that same class as constructor parameter, that doesn't make any sense to me. You can just use that variable in Firstclass class without getting it as a parameter, it already has access to it. To your main question, I think what you want is something like that:

```java
class Firstclass{
  private String someString = "";

  public void createString(String myString){
    someString = myString;
  }

  public String getSomeString(){
    return someString;
  }
}

class Original{
  public void sometMethod(Firstclass first){
    //using someString from 'first'
    System.out.println(first.getSomeString());  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this question because it asks "is there a better way to do this?"

It sounds like you have a situation where you have some value, let's assume an Integer, that will be used across a few objects. "Should I be duplicating this value, or should I be using the same value?" is an important question.

Let's say that the string is something that will be used multiple places and will not change over the lifecycle of the application, but you want the flexibility of changing the contents of the string in one place. For example, if you are building a game, the number of lives you allow your users might be an Integer used across the application. A good pattern for this is a [constant](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076481/learn-java/use-constant-types-for-safer-and-cleaner-code.html). For example:

```
public interface ApplicationConstants {
    public static Integer PLAYER_LIVES_COUNT = 3;
}
```

Then any class that needs the constants can simply implement the constants interface:

```
public class Application implements ApplicationConstants {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FirstClass firstClass = new FirstClass(PLAYER_LIVES_COUNT);
        FirstClass superObject = new FirstClass(PLAYER_LIVES_COUNT);
    }
}
```

This is a better pattern than hardcoding the number 3 around your application because you have one place to control this number. No "find and replace."

What if the FirstClass object itself is one that is going to get used around the application. It has more than one property that other classes need to access around your application. A good pattern in this case is the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

public final class FirstClassFactory {

```
private static FirstClass instance = null;
private FirstClassFactroy() {
}

public static synchronized Singleton getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new FirstClass();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

}

Then around your application, you can change the values of your FirstClass instance at runtime, and the values will change for any object that is using your FirstClass:

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FirstClass firstClass = FirstClassFactory.getInstance();

        firstClass.setPlayerLives(3);
    }
}
```

If another class in your application calls `FirstClassFactory.getInstance()`, it will receive the instance that already has playerLives set to 3.

Lastly, say you have a use case where you need to add more data and functionality to the FirstClass object. A good pattern might be either extension or a [wrapper or decorator pattern](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=258). For example:

```
public class LivesManager {

    private FirstClass firstClass;
    private String statusMessage = "Number of lives remaining: ";

    public LivesManager(FirstClass firstClass) {
        this.firstClass = firstClass;
    }

    public void decrementRemainingLives() {
        --firstClass.getLives();
    }

    public String getLivesMessage() {
        return statusMessage + firstClass.getLives();
    }
}
```

A final note: as mentioned in the comments, it's good practice to make class variables private and use getters and setters to obtain access to the variable. For example:

```
public class FirstClass {

    private Integer lives;

    public FirstClass(Integer lives) {
        this.lives = lives;
    }

    public Integer getLives() {
        return lives;
    }

    public void setLives(Integer lives) {
        this.lives = lives;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps, and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

*"This worked, but I want to know, would it be possible to create the object in the original class and then use it in a different class? Is there a benefit to doing that?"*

**Yes, it is possible. I will illustrate a simple example of it:**

**Class A:**

Has a Random object defined within it(Random rand = new Random();).
And usually getter method called getRandomizer();

```
public Random getRandomizer(){
  return rand;
}
```

**Class B:**

Class B can instantiate Class A.

```
A _object = new A();
```

The random object was created in class A, however after
instantiating class A in class B we have now access to the generally public methods.

We can now simply access the Random object by:

```
_object.getRandomizer();
```

(_object is just a variable name I've defined).